# Cap Or Plug For Sewage Line

Tags: plumbing, sewer

Doing a remodel, and moving a sink about 6 feet from it's original location, and due to the way that the sewer main runs it logically makes more sense to tie into a different sewage line than the current one.

What I have is 2'' PVC pipe and I'm thinking I just need [Zurn 2 Inch Cleanout Plug](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Zurn-2-in-Cleanout-Plug-LC-2P/205974583) but have never messed with sewage lines before so want to confirm before I do something silly.  I've got a `cable saw` that I plan to use to cut the 2`` PVC Pipe (a little concerned about a straight/clean cut due to the small area I'm working in), so I can get the PVC cut, just need to know how to plug/cap it off.

Comment: You don’t need that straight or clean of a cut, sure it needs to be in the ballpark of square but a 1/8” angle in the cut is no big deal and after the cut I usually bevel or chamfer the inside edge so the plug won’t hang up on any burrs. When cutting don’t press hard during the cut you don’t want the old pvc to crack also don’t let it flop around. The seal on a drain stack doesn’t usually require much to seal remember the drains are vented and under normal conditions there is no real pressure just the weight of falling water. As far as cap or plug I use plugs in slabs ether where space is larg

Comment: @EdBeal -> would the cleanout plug I linked to work?  Or is there a different one I should use? .... i'd prefer one that I can get in store, instead of waiting on shipping but beggers can't be choosers

Comment: Those plugs look similar to ones I have used. I have not used that brand but it looks ok to me.